# PHP Injection protect function

Tags: php, mysql

Hello I am searching over the internet for protection from attacks
and I have gathered some codes but I am not sure if they are doing the same job
or if they even are useless or not.
1-2 Tips is also welcome I am new in php.
Here is the function I use for every thing goes in/out of my sql:

```
public static function safe($str = '')
{
    $ret_string = $str;
    $ret_string = htmlspecialchars($ret_string);
    $ret_string = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($ret_string) : mysql_escape_string($ret_string);
    $ret_string = strip_tags($ret_string);
    $ret_string = stripslashes($ret_string);
    $ret_string = htmlspecialchars($ret_string);
    $ret_string = trim(htmlentities($ret_string));
    $ret_string = trim($ret_string);
    $ret_string = str_replace('\\l', '', $ret_string);
    $ret_string = str_replace('\\', '', $ret_string);
    $ret_string = str_replace("%00", "",$ret_string);
    $ret_string = str_replace(' ', '', $ret_string);
    $ret_string = str_replace("'", "", $ret_string);
    $ret_string = str_replace("\"", "",$ret_string);
    $ret_string = str_replace("--", "",$ret_string);
    $ret_string = str_replace("-", "",$ret_string);
    $ret_string = str_replace("^", "",$ret_string);
    $ret_string = str_replace("&", "",$ret_string);
    $ret_string = str_replace("%", "",$ret_string);
    $ret_string = str_replace("(", "",$ret_string);
    $ret_string = str_replace(")", "",$ret_string);
    $ret_string = str_replace("=", "",$ret_string);
    $ret_string = str_replace("+", "",$ret_string);
    $ret_string = str_replace(";", "",$ret_string);
    $ret_string = str_replace(":", "",$ret_string);
    $ret_string = str_replace("|", "",$ret_string);
    $ret_string = str_replace("<", "",$ret_string);
    $ret_string = str_replace(">", "",$ret_string);
    $ret_string = str_replace("~", "",$ret_string);
    $ret_string = str_replace("`", "",$ret_string);
    //Extra ANSI attacks
    $ret_string = str_replace("0x22", "",$ret_string);
    $ret_string = str_replace("0x25", "",$ret_string);
    $ret_string = str_replace("0x27", "",$ret_string);
    $ret_string = str_replace("0x5c", "",$ret_string);
    $ret_string = str_replace("0x5f", "",$ret_string);
    //Extra hex attacks
    $ret_string = str_replace("\x00", "",$ret_string);
    $ret_string = str_replace("\n", "",$ret_string);
    $ret_string = str_replace("\r", "",$ret_string);
    $ret_string = str_replace("\x1a", "",$ret_string);
    $ret_string = str_replace("%20and%20", "",$ret_string);
    return $ret_string;
}
```

Comment: if you really _had_ to you could do `$ret_string = str_replace(['\\l','\\',…], '', $ret_string);`

Comment: You should not search for specific functions, but rather inform yourself where the actual threat/problem lies with SQL injection – once you understand that, you should be able to know what to do against it as well. // Apart from that, the function you have shown here is total BS – it _messes up_ the data by removing a lot of characters from it, which is of course not what one would want. (Imagine this site here would take the same stupid approach – then you would not even have been able to post this code including those characters here to discuss it …)

Comment: Grab this by the horns and throw it into the sun. This is **the worst**. What you've got here is the equivalent of [homeopathy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeopathy) for programming. Read up on [best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#databases) and [SQL escaping fundamentals](http://bobby-tables.com/php).

Comment: Start here to get an actual _understanding_ of the problem: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection

Comment: As I said on Mr.Dai i really dont know how i would like a correction in this function if is possible, to change all the classes to use prepared statements is something big for me and I cannot do this alone, i came here to take some help after 1 month of search and tests.At the moment the site works i tryed some programs that use php injection like havij and i didnt found any holes until now, sorry if i am not good. Thank you for the answers.

Comment: You could always simplify this to just one line: `$ret_string = '';`.... that is guaranteed to sanitize any input.... it's the method most government sites use to silence any criticism of their policies

Comment: I dont need any help you make me feel bad because I dont know some stuf I wont coming here again. delete my question or what ever bye

Comment: You've been given three good links in the comments here telling you how best to prevent SQL injection without crippling user input: yes, switching to prepared statements with bind variables may be a big task, but you said you "wanted to rebuild it" so rebuilding it the right way is a better approach than trying to stick a bandaid over a bad solution to the problem

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to do this. Use prepared statements with parameters, that way you don't need to escape anything.

Comment: It is 100% safe, easy to implement and as indicated by the author of this answer you will not make any mistakes

Comment: The php I use is an old cms of topsites and its work discontinued by the developer but I like it and i wanted to rebuild it, its like 5 years old and it wasnt using prepared statements and to say the truth besides the big rework that needs to change I dont know how so I used search and i fixed it with the old style but I am not sure if it is correct, thank you for the answer.